# Regex expression not working with once or none

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Below is my regex:

```
[^4\d{3}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$]
```

But it throws an error at `-`. I am using `?`, which should allows `-` to appear zero or one time. Why it is giving errors?

Comment: What do you mean? If input is `-` [there is no match](https://regex101.com/r/aD1qZ5/1). And it works [with those examples](https://regex101.com/r/aD1qZ5/2). Where/how do are you using that regex?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want hyphen to come once or none at that point.

Comment: Are you trying to include brackets in your regex? Brackets are an escaped character because they are used for character ranges. Escape it by using `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you enclose the pattern with `[` and `]` - remove them. Am I right? :)

Comment: @stribizhev u made my day :)

Comment: @waleedansari in the future when asking a question, please provide success and failure criteria so that people trying to answer your question don't waste time trying to figure out *what* you are trying to get. Provide examples for better answers! :)

Comment: The problem with this question is the fact that the error was so evident that we refused to see it. The square brackets just can't be used for grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the regex is that the pattern is enclosed with `[` and `]` that are treated as character class markers (see [*Character Classes or Character Sets*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)):

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`.

In character classes, `-` creates ranges between literal characters. In your case, these ranges are not valid (go from a character with higher values to those with lower values) since the `{4}` and other subpatterns were treated as separate characters, not special constructs:

[image]

So, all you need to do is *remove* the `[` and `]` on both sides:

```
^4\d{3}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD1qZ5/2).

Comment: Yup. I got this. Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed, the OP might want to check the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) before posting another question.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes, I wish there was some filter like that. Maybe regex related questions should be posted only from the regex tag wiki page :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping `-` with `\` and remove `[` and `]`:

```
^4\d{3}\-?\d{4}\-?\d{4}\-?\d{4}$
```

Comment: I highly doubt that is what OP needs. Escaping the hyphen will remove the error, but will not correct the expression itself.

Comment: @stribizhev But OP didn't said what (s)he wants to match with this regex.

Comment: So, what does *your* regex supposed to match?

Comment: @stribizhev I don't know. I just removed the error.

Comment: Quantifiers or classes cannot be used within a character set because a set matches one character at a time which breaks the entire regex. Removing the brackets should solve this.