# regex for specific pattern with special characters

Tags: regex, r

I have the following in a data.frame in r:

```
example <- "Inmuebles24_|.|_Casa_|.|_Renta_|.|_NuevoLeon"
```

I would like to simply use `stringr` count and some basic `grexpr` functions on the string, but i'm stuck on the regex.

The delimiter is clearly (and confusingly): `_|.|_`

How would this be expressed with regex?

Currently trying to escape everything to no success:

```
str_count(string = example, pattern = "[\\_\\|\\.\\|\\_]")
```

Comment: Why don't you try splitting? `strsplit("_\\|\\.\\|_", x)` and then count on the returned items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex does not work because you placed it into a character class (where you do not need to escape `_`, BTW). See my today's answer to [*Regex expression not working with once or none*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34766090/3832970) for an explanation of the issue (mainly, the characters are treated as separate symbols and not as sequences of symbols, and all the special symbols are treated as literals, too).

You can achieve what you want in two steps:

- Trim the string from the delimiters with `gsub`
- Use `str_count` + 1 to get the count (as the number of parts = number of delimiters inside the string + 1)

R code:

```
example <- "_|.|_Inmuebles24_|.|_Casa_|.|_Renta_|.|_NuevoLeon_|.|_"
str_count(string = gsub("^(_[|][.][|]_)+|(_[|][.][|]_)+$", "", example), pattern = "_\\|\\.\\|_") + 1
## => 4
```

Or, in case you have multile consecutive delimiters, you need another intermediate step to "contract" them into 1:

```
example <- "_|.|_Inmuebles24_|.|_Casa_|.|__|.|_Renta_|.|__|.|_NuevoLeon_|.|_"
example <- gsub("((_[|][.][|]_)+)", "_|.|_", example)
str_count(string = gsub("^(_[|][.][|]_)+|(_[|][.][|]_)+$", "", example), pattern = "_\\|\\.\\|_") + 1
## => 4
```

Notes on the regexps: `_[|][.][|]_` matches `_|.|_` literally as symbols in the `[...]` character classes lose their special meaning. `((_[|][.][|]_)+)` (2) matches 1 or more (`+`) sequences of these delimiters. The `^(_[|][.][|]_)+|(_[|][.][|]_)+$` pattern matches 1 or more delimiters at the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you what you want for this specific example you've given: `str_count(example, "\\w+")`

Comment: I added `\\d` since we're not sure if some elements can be all numeric.

Comment: I believe the words inside the delimiters are fake and there can be more than just word characters.

Comment: @stribizhev When u r dealing with R questions, most of them provided the exact input.. Some who avoids general solution should receive more no of votes than who provided a general solution.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Good point... It's late in the day for me and the fact that `\\w` captures digits slipped my mind. Thanks for pointing it out.