# Regular Expression to restrict some special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regular expression to restrict some characters. The character to restrict is based on the requirement from various users.

I am trying to use this regex - `[(char1|char2|char3|...)$]` 
Note: Each char will be from requirement.

If the user entered string matches any of the character i ll return true. Now,
what I want to know is weather this expression will work for all the conditions?

For example - `requirement1 = .:, requirement2 = .:&%`

I will concatinate `|` in between each char and then i will generate regular expression in java. This is working for my requirement1 but not for requirement2.

my sample java code

```
String requirement = ":>&%";
String regExp1 = null;
for (int i = 0; i < requirement.length(); i++) {
    regExp1 = "[(" + requirement.charAt(i);
    if (i - 1 != requirement.length()) {
        regExp1.concat("|");
    }
}
if (regExp1 != null) {
    regExp1.concat(")]$");
}
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(arg);
if (m.find())
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

How can I generate standard regular expression?

Comment: Please add the code that is supposed to generate the regex.

Comment: You need to keep special characters in mind, the dot is a special character in regular expressions...

Comment: `[(char1|char2|char3|...)$]` is a misunderstanding of character class vs. grouping. [Using character classes where not necessary leads to unexpected issues.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765780/regex-expression-not-working-with-once-or-none/34766090#34766090)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "one of these characters" the brackets are good enough. No need for parenthesis and pipes.

Something like this : `[.:,]` and `[.:&%]` may work. If want them one or more times you have to had `+` at the end of your regex (ie: `[.:&%]+`).

As said in the comments, beware of special chars (like the dot, which means any chars in regex).

Comment: Thank you so much Django Janny. Your answer is working perfectly.

Comment: @user3778890 Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.

Comment: @SwathiN you're welcome, and user1803551 is right, can you accept the anwser ?