# How to replace semicolon except when encountering data uri specific text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am replacing all semicolons with line breaks but I have to make a few exceptions.

```
results = results.replace(/;/g, "\n");
```

But now I have 3 cases where I do not want to replace the semicolon:

- data:image/png;
- data:image/jpeg;
- data:image/gif;

Basically any thing:

- data:image/*;

I have tried:

```
results = results.replace(/^(data:image/png;)|;/g, "\n");
```

But it doesn't work.

This kind of works but it replaces the semicolon and one preceding character:

```
results = results.replace(/[^(data:image/png;)];/g, "\n");
```

Test data:

```
borderradius:10;borderradius:20;background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQUAAAGQCAYAAACnPXVhAAAz9ElEQVR4Ae2d2a8VxdqH+QO44YaECxISQ0IICSGEEAghEoKBQEEbfXUX7JizwEBUFBUJAGPA0IChKEJwh59uR59rjrLIACO/pTGUgD0gAa+D+0cw+oAw0jjQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^(data:image/png;)];` contains a common user error: a character class (single character matching pattern) is used where a grouping construct (sequence 
matching pattern) is meant to be used. See [*Regex expression not working with once or none*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765780/regex-expression-not-working-with-once-or-none/34766090#34766090) for a similar issue.

You may use a regex *capturing* the `data:image/[something];` and then use a callback to decide whether to keep the capture or replace the `;` with a linebreak:

```js
var s = "data:image/png; data/png; text";
var res = s.replace(/\b(data:image\/[^\/;]*;)|;/g, function (_, $1) {
    return $1 ? $1 : "\n";
  });
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + res + "</pre>";
```

The `/\b(data:image\/[^\/;]*;)|;/g` will match multiple occurrences of:

- `\b(data:image\/[^\/;]*;)` - Group 1 capturing a whole word `data:image` followed with `/`, then with zero or more characters other than `/` and `;` up to the first `;`
- `|` - or..
- `;` - a literal semicolon (just matched, no capturing group is used here)

In the callback, if `$1` is set (not null), we restore the captured text with `$1`, and if not, we just replace with `\n` since we matched a "stray" `;`.

Comment: Amazing! I would like to give the first parameter a name. What is it's purpose?

Comment: Is it possible to get more than 2 arguments? ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Function/<anonymous>(). Expected 2, got 4.

Comment: Excuse me, what do you want to do? Use `function (match_value, capture_group_1) {...}`? You can do it like that, sure. I assume you are using JavaScript.

Comment: I was getting four arguments in the anonymous function. I added a `...args` parameter to capture unknown number of arguments and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: See [`string.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) reference: the 4+ arguments to the callback function are 1) match text, 2) capture group 1...n, 3) offset of the match, 4) input string. See sample function signature: `function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string)` - where p1, p2 and p3 are the captured texts.